# C - Getting a SIGABRT error, does not make any sense for me

Tags: c, arrays, realloc, sigabrt

So, my program should read an array of unknown size of positive integers in the format {1,2,3,4,5}, process it into an array, and then start reading pairs of integers a and b and find the least common multiple of a to (b-1)th elements of that array.
Here's my current solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int gcf(int a, int b) // greatest common divisor
{
    while (a*b!=0)
    {
        if (a<b)
            b=b-a;
        else
            if (b<a)
                a=a-b;
        else
            if (a==b)
                return a;
    }
    return 0;
}

int lcm(int a, int b) // least common multiplier
{
    return a*b/gcf(a,b);
}

int main()
{
    int a,bufUsed=0,bufCurr=0,i,b,signal=1,curlcm;
    char c;
    int* tmp;
    int* array;
    c=getchar();
    if (c!='{')
    {
        printf ("err0");
        return 0;
    }
    while((scanf("%d",&a))==1)
    {
        if (signal==0) // checking for the comma
        {
            printf("err1");
            return 0;
        }
        signal=0;
        printf("%d ",a); // displaying current values, used just for debugging
        if (bufUsed == bufCurr) //resizing the current array 
        {
           bufCurr += 20;
           tmp = (int*)realloc(array, bufCurr); // the line that causes trouble
           if (!tmp)
               printf("err2");
           array = tmp;
        }
        array[bufUsed] = a;
        bufUsed++;
        if (scanf(" %c",&c)==1) // checking for commas or closing bracket
        {
            if (c==',')
            {
                signal=1;
                continue;
            }
            if (c=='}')
                break;
            else
            {
                printf("err3");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("err4");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    while ((scanf("%d %d",&a,&b))==2) // the second part, finding the LCM
    {
        curlcm=lcm(array[a],array[a+1]);
        for (i=2;i<b-a;i++)
        {
            curlcm=lcm(curlcm,array[a+i]);
        }
        printf("%d\n",curlcm);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The line

> tmp = (int*)realloc(array, bufCurr);

seems to be causing the SIGABRT, according to gdb, however, if I remove the second part of the program (finding the LCM while cycle), it works just fine. I've tried checking how the second part works with a defined array in the second program:

```
int main()
{
    int a,i,b,curlcm;
    int array[10];
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        array[i]=i+1;      
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    curlcm=lcm(array[a],array[a+1]);
    for (i=2;i<b-a;i++)
    {
        curlcm=lcm(curlcm,array[a+i]);
    }
    printf("%d",curlcm);
}
```

and it runs just fine as well.

So how come that combining these two causes the SIGABRT? I've tried checking if accessing the array causes the problem, however, this seems not to be the case as well. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: @user0042 Yes, I did. GDB throws the SIGABRT at the " tmp = (int*)realloc(array, bufCurr); " (line 50), however, it makes no sense, since without the second part it works perfectly. I probably should have mentioned that the error is thrown after the first part of the input ( {1,2,3} for example) and before I can even send any pair of integers.

Comment: @user3121023 I know, but I'm not sure that's the problem here, since I don't get the "err2" message and it runs perfectly fine (displaying proper array values if I check them in the for cycle) if I don't use the second while cycle.

Comment: @DanieleNieto What can *realloc* do with an uninitialized *array* address except crash (or UB)? user[0-3]+ is correct.

Comment: @user3121023
Thank you, added the 
    array=(int*)malloc(2);
in the beginning and slightly modified the realloc line, now it runs without any errors even with the lcm cycle. 
Now, a more important question - how do I mark the issue as solved and where should I leave the solution?

Comment: @RingØ: Why not make this an answer, as it *is* fixing the bug.

Comment: Setting `int * array = NULL` had solved the issue as well.

Comment: @alk thanks but user3121023 gets the credit ; he/she removed his/her comment (for some reason). Let's do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the manual, the function

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

> The  realloc()  function  changes  the  size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes.  The contents will be unchanged in the range from the start of the region up to the minimum  of the old and new sizes.  If the new size is larger than the old size, the added memory will not be initialized.  **If ptr is NULL**, then  the  call  is  equivalent  to malloc(size)

In the program, we have

```
int* array;
...
tmp = (int*)realloc(array, bufCurr);
```

calling `realloc` the first time, while the `array` pointer is not initialized.

The memory manager try to read some internal data based on that random address (like the size of the segment vs the requested size) which leads to undefined behavior (crash in your case).

As suggested, a simple solution consists of setting initially `array` to `NULL`, so that `realloc` does a simple `malloc` (since its `ptr` address is `NULL`).

```
int *array = NULL;
```